# Split undirected graph by negative edges

Tags: graph, graph-theory, connected-components

Wondering if there exists an algorithm to split an undirected connected component graph given negative edges.

Essentially the vertices provided in negative edges should be unreachable.

Comment: I guess DFS while removing negative edge should accomplish it - why do you need special algorithm?

Comment: Not sure I understand can you elaborate?

Comment: @AdiGuN Not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish can you elaborate?

Comment: I have a list of edges positive and negative. I'm looking to build connected components with positive edges such that each connected component does not have any negative edges

Comment: If you don't want any negative edges in the connected component(s), then, as suggested before, use only the positive edges when you run your connected component algorithm. I am unsure what part you need elaboration on.

Comment: Just remove negative edges and compute connected components. (This kind of questions are more likely to get answers on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the connected components of your graph that contains only positive edges, then first delete all negative edges from your graph. Then run a DFS (depth-first-search) to find all connected components.

Here is the algorithm.

```
Begin 
    For each edge e in graph G, if e is negative, remove e from G.

    For each vertex v in G, do:
        If v is not labeled as visited
            Let c be a new component, and add c to set C.
            Call procedure DFS(v, c) to find one component of positive edges only.
        End If
    End For

    The set C contains all the connected components consisting of positive edges only.
End

Procedure DFS(v, c)
    Add v to c, and label v as visited.
    For each edge from v to w, do
        If vertex w is not labeled as visited then
            Call DFS(G,w)
        End If
    End For
End Procedure
```